# Python: read all files from directory

Tags: python

I am trying to write code that will read all the text files from a directory and find if any file has text like:

```
'this is color=green'
'its color=orange'
```

Then it has to print the specific color. My code isn't printing the output:

```
import os
path = r'C:\Python27' 
data = {}

for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
    dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
        with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
            data[dir_entry] = my_file.read()
            for line in my_file:
                for part in line.split():
                    if "color=" in part:
                        print part
```

My output has to look like:

```
color=green
color=orange
```

I could do it for individual files but when it comes to directory, I don't get output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, you're reading the file twice and hence the pointer is at the end of the file.

If you actually want data to be propagated with the contents of your files as well as printing the relevant color lines, you could read from data:

```
data = {}

for dir_item in os.listdir(path):
    dir_item_path = os.path.join(path, dir_item)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_item_path):
        with open(dir_item_path, 'r') as f:
            data[dir_item] = f.read()
            for part in data[dir_item].split():
                if part.startswith('color='):
                    print part[6:]
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're reading the contents of the file twice:

```
data[dir_entry] = my_file.read()
for line in my_file:
```

so the entire contents of the file are in data[dir_entry] and the file handle is now at the end of my_file, with nothing left to read. If you just use the 'for line in my_file:' method, it should work:

```
for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
    dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
        with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                for part in line.split():
                    if "color=" in part:
                        print part
```

Comment: i need to avoid printing "color=",how to edit for that

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
path = r'C:\Python27' 
data = {}

found = False
for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
    dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
        with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
            a = my_file.readlines()
            for line in a:
                for part in line.split():
                    if "color=" in part:
                        print part.split('=')[1]
```

EDIT: changed the code according to comment,

Comment: its great but i need to avoid printing "color=" in my output,so could u tell me how to do it?

Comment: do you want to in the dictionary only the files that have 'color=' inside?

Comment: i mean the output displays as "color=" /ncolor=red/ncolor=orange,so i need to avoid the first "color=" and just print color=red/n color=orange.I think u got it!